# Writing in WPF problems

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I'm  trying to write for the first time in WPF and I see that I can't manage the icons in the menus.
My Code is that.

```
<Grid>
        <my:RibbonControl Height="49" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="RibbonControl1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="503" />
        <my:Ribbon Name="Ribbon">
            <my:RibbonTab Name="Manage" Header="Διαχείριση" KeyTip="m">
                <my:RibbonGroup Name="groupadd" Header="Χρήστες">
                    <my:RibbonSplitButton x:Name="btnUser" LargeImageSource="/Economy;component/Images/users01.png" Width="30" Height="60" TabIndex="1" FontFamily="Palatino Linotype" FontSize="12" FocusedBackground="#FFE2AB7F" LayoutTransform="{Binding}" MaxHeight="120" MaxWidth="80" Margin="1,0,0,1" OverridesDefaultStyle="False" Padding="0" ToolTipFooterTitle="Επιλογή">
                        <MenuItem Header="Ανάθεση">
                             <MenuItem.Icon>
                                <Image Source="/Economy;component/Images/delegation.jpg" Stretch="Fill" Width="20" Height="20"/>
                            </MenuItem.Icon>
                        </MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem Header="Διαγραφή">
                            <MenuItem.Icon>
                                <Image Source="/Economy;component/Images/deletion.ico" Stretch="Fill" Width="20" Height="20" />
                            </MenuItem.Icon>
                        </MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem Header="Είσοδος">
                            <MenuItem.Icon>
                                <Image Source="/Economy;component/Images/login.jpg" Stretch="Fill" Width="20" Height="20"/>
                            </MenuItem.Icon>
                        </MenuItem>
                        <my:RibbonSeparator />
                        <MenuItem Header="Έξοδος">
                            <MenuItem.Icon>
                                <Image Source="/Economy;component/Images/logout.ico"  Stretch="Fill" Width="20" Height="20"/>
                            </MenuItem.Icon>
                        </MenuItem>
                    </my:RibbonSplitButton>
                </my:RibbonGroup>
            </my:RibbonTab>
        </my:Ribbon>
    </Grid>
```

this code produces the following

[image]

What I need is to have the icons at the most left site of the menu.
I read another question about that... which is

```
<ribbon:RibbonSplitButton x:Name="SplitButton3DViews" 
               ItemsSource="{Binding items}"
               Label="Views3D"
               IsCheckable="False" >
    <ribbon:RibbonSplitButton.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ribbon:RibbonMenuItem}">
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Path=Name}" />
            <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Path=cmd}" />
            <Setter Property="ImageSource" Value="{Binding Icon}" />
        </Style>
    </ribbon:RibbonSplitButton.Resources>                        
</ribbon:RibbonSplitButton>
```

But it is not working with my page... 
Is there some one to assist me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, please state which ribbon control library you are using, as `<my:Ribbon>` is not part of the built-in .NET framework.

Secondly, I think that `<MenuItem>` is the wrong element to use inside your ribbon control.
According to this webpage:
http://www.renevo.com/blogs/dotnet/archive/2009/02/10/your-first-wpf-ribbon-application.aspx

a `RibbonApplicationMenuItem` should be used instead, no mention of `MenuItem` anywhere. You might not be using the same ribbon control as shown in the webpage, but I'm guessing that your ribbon control requires another element instead of `Menuitem`.

Comment: The namespace is: Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon The Assembly name is: RibbonControlsLibrary... I was download it from the internet... because when I start WPF I couldn't find a way to use Menus...

Comment: @LefterisGkinis - for very basic WPF menu - http://wpftutorial.net/Menus.html
And the microsoft ribbon control still requires the use RibbonApplicationMenuItem - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windows.controls.ribbon(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Well I do have a good Menu... but not so good as the ribbon menu

Comment: @LefterisGkinis - the WPF built-in menu is very basic as a I said. If you want a better looking menu, then the RibbonControl is a good choice, but you must learn how to use it properly. I already provided the answer for your original question - you must use RibbonApplicationMenuItem (or similar) element. I'm sure you can find good tutorials for the RibbonControl via google...